# PHP while shell_exec Kill -9

Tags: php, ubuntu, while-loop

I have once asked again, I see something I will not use a while loop to go through to kill processes, unfortunately, the error message is heard in the apache log?

```
    sh: line 0: kill: 27185
: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

That this is not sure, I'm aware I just want to understand something :) hope to help

PHP Code:

```
$box=$_POST['delete'];
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($box)) {
    $exe="kill -9 $val";
    shell_exec($exe);

}
```

greeting

Comment: what does the `echo "$val";` outputs?

Comment: to see if it passes the PIDs

Comment: It looks like `$val` ends with an escaped newline.

Comment: OT: why do you have `." "`?

Comment: I've just seen too, unfortunately it was not because. how can I fail best fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$box=$_POST['delete'];
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($box)) {
    if (!empty($val) && is_numeric($val)) { // $val is not 0 or an empty string, and is a number.
        $exe="kill -9 $val";
        shell_exec($exe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @MohitJain What isn't clear? It is some really basic validation that checks if the $val is not 0 or an empty string(the empty function), and makes sure it's a number(is_numeric).

Comment: the code it does not matter - I just do not understand, it passes the PIDs via checkbox kill but he does not